# Simple Vegan cookies recipe

Tags: cookies, vegan

I am trying to make a recipe with the following ingredients.
2 cups blanched almond flour (240 grams)
1/2 teaspoon baking soda (4 grams)
1/4 teaspoon sea salt (2 grams)
1/4 cup melted coconut oil (54 grams)
1/4 cup maple syrup (85 grams; at room temperature)
1 teaspoon vanilla extract (5 grams)
1 teaspoon apple cider vinegar (5 grams)
1/2 cup mini chocolate chips (88 grams)

1. Does any one see a problem with me switching the almond flour with regular all purpose flour?
2. If switching is okay, then how would the other quantities change.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Unfortunately recipe requests are considered off-topic / against the rules for this site, so your question will likely be closed. If you have an existing recipe and need help with substitutions, modifications, or "fixing" something that doesn't turn out, that is an acceptable variation that would be well received here.

Comment: Woops, sorry about that. Let me rephrase the question. TY

Comment: Are you trying to swap almond flour for wheat flour in a recipe written for wheat flour, or the other way around?  Your wording is ambiguous.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I am trying to swap almond flour for wheat flour in a recipe written for Almond flour.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just swap almond flour for wheat flour and expect a recipe to work.  The properties of the two flours are far too different.  Likely the cookies would end up as hard rocks.  You could play with butter content and several other things, but it doesn't seem worth the effort.

I strongly suggest starting with a recipe for regular wheat-flour cookies instead; there are many such vegan recipes.

Comment: I agree that it is not trivial to substitute one flour for another. But since AP flour will give some gluten development and is lower in fat, I doubt if the cookies will melt into a puddle any more with AP flour than almond flour.

Comment: It seems like you confused the question: OP has a recipe that uses almond flour, and wants to use AP flour instead.

Comment: That's absolutely not clear from the question; it could be read either way.  The OP needs to clarify.

Comment: Either way, though, the swap is a bad idea.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I said "Does any one see a problem with me switching the almond flour with regular all purpose flour?:......I did make it absolutely clear that I have  a recipe that uses almond flour and want to use AP flour instead.

Comment: Updated answer to take this into account.